# Mismatch error/ code not working

Tags: excel, vba

This is the updated code. I am getting a mismatch error now. It would be great if someone could offer some help. Thanks in advance!

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim rowcount As Long

Dim target As Variant, startcell4 As Range

Set startcell4 = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1)

rowcount = Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For i = 2 To rowcount + 1

    If Not ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 26) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 26) Then

    Set target = Application.Match(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 26), Worksheets(19).Range("A6:A3000"), 0)


        If Not IsError(target) Then

        ActiveSheet.startcell4.Offset(0, 17).Value = Worksheets(19).Cells(target + 6, 10)

        Set startcell4 = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 26)

        End If

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: The `match function` will return the number of the row in Range("A6:A3000"), where value of ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 26) can be found.  For example if Cells(i, 26) can be found cell A9, the match function will return the value 3 as it is the third value in Range("A6:A3000").

Comment: I updated it according to what you said, but I am still not getting an output.

Comment: Change "Set target = ..." to "target = ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed:

- "Set target = ..." to "target = ..."
- "ActiveSheet.startcell4" to "startcell4"
- A little refactoring

Coming to this

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim rowcount As Long
    Dim target As Variant, startcell4 As Range

    Set startcell4 = Cells(2, 1)
    rowcount = Range("E2").End(xlDown).Row
    For i = 2 To rowcount
        If Not Cells(i, 26) = Cells(i + 1, 26) Then
            target = Application.Match(Cells(i, 26), Worksheets(19).Range("A6:A3000"), 0)
            If Not IsError(target) Then
                startcell4.Offset(0, 17).Value = Worksheets(19).Cells(target + 6, 10)
                Set startcell4 = Cells(i + 1, 26)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```